# DbSet does not contain definition for SaveChanges

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to delete a selected row in my datagrid as well as that same row in my database.

I'm getting an error though where dbset does not contain a definition for `SaveChanges`.

Relatively new to Linq and EF. Anyone know where this might be coming from?

```
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        using (EFContext db = new EFContext())
        {
            int proId = (ProductDatagrid.SelectedItem as Product).ProductID;
            Result result = (from r in db.products where r.ProductID == proId select r).SingleOrDefault();
            db.Product.Remove(result);
            db.Product.SaveChanges();

            ProductDatagrid.ItemsSource = db.Results.ToList();
        }
}
```

Comment: Been a while since I've done any EF, but isn't `SaveChanges()` supposed to be called on the `EFContext` object, in this case `db`?

Comment: Does the query `from r in db.products select r` return a collection of `Result` objects? I assume your db.products are mapped to a `Product` model, not a `Result` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `.Product` from the `Remove()` and `SaveChanges()` methods. The `Result result` will be tracked by Entity Framework so it will know which table to remove your `record` from and then you can call `db.SaveChanges()` without any errors since it is being called on the DbContext (`EfContext`):

```
   using (EFContext db = new EFContext())
    {
        int proId = (ProductDatagrid.SelectedItem as Product).ProductID;

        Result result = (from r in db.products where r.ProductID == proId select r).SingleOrDefault();

        // .Product removed
        db.Remove(result);
        db.SaveChanges();

        ProductDatagrid.ItemsSource = db.Results.ToList();

    }
```

But if you want to continue with the syntax of using `db.Product`, then you can also attach the `Result` object to the dbContext without the query like this:

```
   using (EFContext db = new EFContext())
    {
        int proId = (ProductDatagrid.SelectedItem as Product).ProductID;

        Result result = new Result { ProductId = proId};

        db.Product.Attach(result);
        db.Product.Remove(result);
        db.Product.SaveChanges();

        ProductDatagrid.ItemsSource = db.Results.ToList();

    }
```

Or you can set the entity state to deleted and remove it that way:

```
   using (EFContext db = new EFContext())
    {
        int proId = (ProductDatagrid.SelectedItem as Product).ProductID;

        Result result = new Result { ProdId = proId };

        db.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        db.SaveChanges();

        ProductDatagrid.ItemsSource = db.Results.ToList();

    }
```